# Batch Manipulation in the VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I'm working with the video editing part of Blender, and I was wanting to change the proxy video settings on all of the videos in my project in the sequencer. But I had to go to each individual video to do so. It took up a lot of time. Is there a way to do it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some toggles, you can first select multiple strips, then right click on them and choose *"Copy to Selected"*.

For batch controls on proxy quality setting, there is a very nice VSE addon **[here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?338598-Addon-WIP-VSE-Quick-functions-Snaps-Fades-Zoom-Parenting-Titling-Play-speed)**, which can make it much easier.

[image]